# Delete single items from parse array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, parse-platform

I am trying to delete items from my Parse array. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

```
func deletePhoto(sender:UIButton) {
    let i : Int = (sender.layer.valueForKey("index")) as! Int
    let image = facebookPics[i]
    PFUser.currentUser()?.removeObject(facebookPics[i], forKey: "images")
    PFUser.currentUser()?.saveInBackground()
    facebookPics.removeAtIndex(i)
    self.mainCollectionView!.reloadData()

}
```

This is happening when I press on an `UIButton` within my `UICollectionViewCell`. It removes it from my array and the rest is happening quite smoothly. What is the problem with **Parse**?

Comment: Where is your collectionview getting its data from? Does reloadData() trigger your app to fetch its data from Parse again and you're expecting the image to not be fetched?

Comment: reloadData() is just there to rearrange the cells. It doesn't trigger a query. I am only trying to remove the object from my Parse-Data

Comment: My question was not about reloadData() itself, but where your collectionview is getting data from... Depending on where your data comes from initially, a call to reloadData might trigger a new fetch from Parse. Please explain where your collectionview data comes from.

Comment: Ah, I see. It is triggered in the viewDidLoad() Method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer:

The problem basically was, that I needed to log back in, as my PFUser.currentUser was nil.

Code was fine though.